# How to select next immediate element in css selector in python selenium?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selenium

I have the DOM structure as follows.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="js-pagination link" data-page="1">1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="js-pagination link active" data-page="2">2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="js-pagination link " data-page="3">3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="js-pagination link " data-page="4">4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have to select next immediate element (not adjacent element) after element that contains `class="js-pagination link active"`. In our case it is third `li` element.
I tried the following css selector

```
"ul li a[class='js-pagination link active'] + li"
```

But it is not working since its looking for `li` in the same level of `a` tag. How can we do it using css selector?

I cannot use .has() since I am using this selector in selenium css select to find elements.

Comment: Are you asking about CSS or javascript?

Comment: What should happen if the `.active` element happens to be in the last of the `<li>` elements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: having .active in the last element wont happen in my case. So currently not considering it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:has()` to select `li` with `a.js-pagination.link.active` and then `.next()` to select next `li` element.

```
$('li:has(a.js-pagination.link.active)').next('li')
```

```js
$('li:has(a.js-pagination.link.active)').next('li').css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" role="button" class="js-pagination link" data-page="1">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" role="button" class="js-pagination link active" data-page="2">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" role="button" class="js-pagination link " data-page="3">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" role="button" class="js-pagination link " data-page="4">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Also there is no `:has()` selector in css so the only way to do this is with js.

Comment: can we do it without using :has(). Since I am using the selector inside my selenium query .It doesnt support :has().

Answer (score 0):

In jquery, you can find the class `.active`, get its `parent()` and find the `next()` siblings

```
$('.active').parent().next().css('background', 'green');
```

```js
  $('.active').parent().next().css('background', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" role="button" class="js-pagination link" data-page="1">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" role="button" class="js-pagination link active" data-page="2">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" role="button" class="js-pagination link " data-page="3">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" role="button" class="js-pagination link " data-page="4">4</a></li>
</ul>
```